# Http Post method firing twice

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have 2 views. View 1 contains a html table and each row contains a link to the view 2.

This is my view1

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="@Url.Action("AssignStudent", "Session", new { slotId = item.TimeSlotId, roomId = item.RoomId, roomName = item.RoomName, starttime = dt })">Assign Session </a> 
    </td>
<tr/>
```

On clicking this It will fire assignstudent method in session controller

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult AssignStudent(SessionDashboardViewModel dashboardModel)
{
    dashboardModel.SessionId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["SessionId"]);
    dashboardModel.RoomId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["hdnRoomId"]);
    dashboardModel.TimeSlotId= Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["hdnSlotId"]);    
    SaveMethod(); //save working fine
    dashboardModel.SessionId = result;  
    ModelState.Clear();
    dashboardModel = InitViewData(dashboardModel);
    return View("SessionDashboard",dashboardModel);// call to source page
}
```

the problem comes once the data is saved I have decided to call the source page but it populates the source page from there  it once again hits this AssignStudent method(I don't know why) and tries to save the data once again resulting in error.

Pls help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your last line of code

```
return RedirectToAction("SessionDashboard", dashboardModel);
```